# using @font-face in codepen

Tags: css, font-face

Is it possible to use @font-face in an application like codepen.io?

I was trying to use a font from github in my codepen. But the font wouldn't load.

https://github.com/TypeNetwork/Decovar/blob/master/fonts/DecovarAlpha-VF.ttf

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Decovar";
  src: url('https://github.com/TypeNetwork/Decovar/blob/master/fonts/DecovarAlpha-VF.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: "Decovar";
}
```

UPDATE :: 
As pointed out there is a CORS issue with loading the font from github. But I don't really understand why I can use a link that loads a CSS stylesheet that defines a font family. But I can't write my own style sheet to include the font. How is one more secure than the other?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/decovar" type="text/css"/>

@font-face {
font-family: 'DecovarRegular24';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/decovar/434ee108e46e353c9914966b169d781b/b6a2e38c243d4f16ad98d2ca3d6cdc24/DecovarRegular24.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I did find this explanation at Mozilla.

> This cross-origin sharing standard is used to enable cross-site HTTP requests for: ...Web Fonts (for cross-domain font usage in @font-face within CSS), so that servers can deploy TrueType fonts that can only be cross-site loaded and used by web sites that are permitted to do so.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

As pointed out by @jacob goh. The reason isn't for security. It's because:

> Github is not a file hosting site and does not allow people to use it as such.

Comment: _“But the font wouldn't load”_ - and a look into the browser console would have told you why already ...

Comment: The link points to an html page, not the font in itself

Comment: look at the console (F12): *[...] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [...]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@font-face is not the problem. The problem is the font file you load.

If the file hosting server has the right setting, CORS issue wouldn't occur.

Github is not a file hosting site and does not allow people to use it as such.

But there is a free service called [Rawgit](http://rawgit.com/) that can help with that.

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/YeWOay

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Decovar";
  src: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/TypeNetwork/Decovar/620fb4ea/fonts/DecovarAlpha-VF.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: "Decovar";
}
```

Comment: Rawgit has stopped. So you might want to add some alternatives to this answer.